# Resizing gif file, save it to memory

Tags: c#, .net, gif

I use the following code for resizing a gif file.

```
public void Resize(int newWidth, int newHeight)
{
    var dimension = new FrameDimension(_image.FrameDimensionsList[0]);
    var frameCount = _image.GetFrameCount(dimension);

        // load frames
    var encoder = new GifBitmapEncoder();
    for (var i = 0; i < frameCount; ++i)
    {
        _image.SelectActiveFrame(dimension, i);
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(
                     new Bitmap(_image, newWidth, newHeight).CreateBitmapSource()));
    }

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        encoder.Save(ms);
        ms.Position = 0;
        _image = new Bitmap(ms);
    }
}

public static BitmapSource CreateBitmapSource(this Bitmap bitmap)
{
    if (bitmap == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("bitmap");

    lock (bitmap)
    {
        IntPtr hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();

        return System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            hBitmap,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            Int32Rect.Empty,
            BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    }
}
```

If I output it to a filestream, the gif is animated (altough the frames seem a little slower), but if i load it into an image, it doesn't matter wether from the memorystream or loading it from the "working" gif that came from the filestream, it only contains 1 frame.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work in the image before the resize?

Comment: Yes, if i don't resize and i save it, it works fine.

Comment: Please post a better code example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. The code you posted seems to be mixing `System.Drawing` types with WPF media types. `System.Drawing.Bitmap` doesn't have a `CreateBitmapSource()` method. So either you're using some different `Bitmap` type, or you've left out the code for some extension method. Finally, by "if I don't resize", what does that mean? If you execute exactly the code you posted, but the `newWidth` and `newHeight` values are identical to the original size? Or something else?

Comment: It was an extension method, wpf image is not used in this code. I edited my post so it contains the extension method. 
As for the previous question, I figured Luaan meant the original image might not have been working, by "if I don't resize" I mean: if the above code is not executed.